# Can iOS app run in Xcode simulator accessing Mac hard drive location (outside sandbox)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I thought iOS app run in simulator is restricted to the simulator itself.  But there is this project called [iOS-Artwork-Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor) that actually accesses Mac hard drive locations outside the simulator environment.  For example, it will read all apps in your itunes, etc.  I am sure it uses non-public APIs.

Does that mean theoretically an iOS App running in Xcode simulator can install "unwanted" code on the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is correct. The simulator does not enforce the sandbox the way an iOS device does, so an app running in the simulator can do anything it wants to the Mac file system.

Since you have the source code for any app you run on the simulator, you should review the code before you run it.

Only developers running Xcode can run apps in the simulator. What are you worried about, trojan horse apps for the simulator targeted at other developers?

Comment: Not sure why Apple has this feature.

Comment: Sandboxing is a relatively new development in OS X, and apps do not have to use sandboxing. Things like installing executable code into the system require you to enter an administrator password however. As a developer you are expected to have a higher level of understanding, and exercise more caution, than average users.

Comment: I spent over a year trying to find a way to do something much more complicated always assuming the simulator wouldn't have disk access! Only today I realised it's possible omg!